# React- redux tutorial - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs, function, react-redux

Im new in react so i try to follow react redux tutorial and got this error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

I'm really appreciate if anyone could help thank you!

below are my code

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


export const PostsList = () => {
const posts = useSelector(state => state.posts)


const renderedPosts = posts.map(posts => (
    <article className="post-excerpt" key={posts.id}>
    <h3>{posts.title}</h3>
    <p className="post-content">{posts.content.substring(0, 100)}</p>
    <Link to={`/posts/${posts.id}`} className="button muted-button">
    View Post
    </Link>
    </article>
))

return (
    <section className="posts-list">
    <h2>Posts</h2>
    {renderedPosts}
    </section>
)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not getting any value from useSelector. I mean **posts** variable is initialed to undefined. That is why you are getting an error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').
Because map can not work on undefined.